# Storing date value into Core Data in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone tell me please how to save only date value to Core Data using objective C? I am using UIDatePicker. I searched a lot, but couldn't find any. Can you be more specific because i am newbie. Thanks

---

Here is my code for adding data to core data database. But instead of formatting dates into string I would like to save as a NSdate. I am creating an calendar app that stores events into CoreData. Is there any help?

```
- (IBAction)btnSave:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *dataRecord = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Scheduler" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [dataRecord setValue:self.txtBxCustomerName.text forKey:@"customerName"];
    [dataRecord setValue: [self date] forKey:@"date"];
    [dataRecord setValue:[self begin] forKey:@"startTime"];
    [dataRecord setValue:[self end] forKey:@"endTime"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)datePicker:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSString *string = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.dateTime.date];
    date = string;
}


- (IBAction)startTimePicker:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString *str = [timeFormat stringFromDate:self.startTime.date];
    begin = str;
}

- (IBAction)endTimePicker:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *endTimeFormatt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [endTimeFormatt setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString *sting = [endTimeFormatt stringFromDate:self.endTime.date];
    end = sting;
}
```

Comment: Your question is really vague. Try to be more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: I am using Date Picker to select certain date and want to store that date into core data. But it shows me an error.

Comment: What's the error?  How is the date attribute defined in your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the date from the picker with

```
NSDate *chosenDate = myDatePicker.date;
```

and then set it to the desired attributed (in the example `startDate`) of your model, which should be define in Core Data as type Date

```
myCoreDataObject.startDate = chosenDate;
```

or even shorter

```
myCoreDataObject.startDate = myDatePicker.date;
```